# The following VBA code breaks. How may I keep it running?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Base 1

Sub PrepareIOFile()

'Step 1: Open Final SPQ for eDPSS and find the earliest start date
Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer

i = 2
Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value)
i = i + 1
Loop
LastRow = i - 1
rowCount = i - 2

'Step 2: Find the earliest start date in the records
Dim EarliestDate As Date
Dim FirstDate As Date

EarliestDate = CDate(Application.Min(Range("K2:K" & LastRow)))
FirstDate = EarliestDate

'Step 3: Find the number of months between earliest start date and specified month
Dim NowMonth As Integer
Dim NowYear As Integer

NowMonth = InputBox("Please specify the most recent month to compute." & vbNewLine & "Note: Month should be between 1 and 12 only.")

If NowMonth < 1 Or NowMonth > 12 Then

    MsgBox "You have entered an invalid month."
    Exit Sub

Else

    NowMonth = NowMonth
    NowYear = InputBox("Please specify the current year to compute." & vbNewLine & "Note: The year should be entered in the yyyy format.")

    If NowYear < 2008 Or NowYear > Year(Date) Then

        MsgBox "The valid year should be between Year 2008 and Year " & Year(Date) & "."
        Exit Sub

    Else

        NowMonth = NowMonth
        NowYear = NowYear

    End If

End If

Dim NowDate As Date
Dim MonthRange As Integer

NowDate = CDate("1/" & NowMonth & "/" & NowYear)
EarliestDate = CDate("1/" & Month(FirstDate) & "/" & Year(FirstDate))
MonthRange = Round((NowDate - EarliestDate) / 30.4)

'Step 4: Prepare the output file
Dim MyPath As String
MyPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\output.xls"

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs MyPath

Worksheets("Sheet1").Select

Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Basic Price"
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Contract No"
Range("C1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Project Title"
Range("D1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Contract Start"
Range("E1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Contract End"
Range("F1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ASPQ"
Range("G1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Qty Delivered"
Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Cumulative TD"
Range("H2").Select

Dim StartMonth As String
StartMonth = Month(EarliestDate) & "/1/" & Year(EarliestDate)
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = StartMonth
Selection.NumberFormat = "mmmyy"

Dim CurrentMonth As String
For i = 1 To MonthRange
    CurrentMonth = Month(CDate(DateAdd("m", 1, EarliestDate))) & "/1/" & Year(CDate(DateAdd("m", 1, EarliestDate)))
    Cells(2, 8 + i).Value = CurrentMonth
    Cells(2, 8 + i).NumberFormat = "mmmyy"
    EarliestDate = DateAdd("m", 1, EarliestDate)
Next i

ActiveWorkbook.Close

'Capture Contract no. and its accompanying information
Dim OutputPath As String
OutputPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\output.xls"

Dim ContractNo As String
Dim ProjectTitle As String
Dim ContractStart As String
Dim ContractEnd As String
Dim ASPQ As Double

j = 1
For j = 1 To LastRow
    ContractNo = Cells(j + 1, 1).Value
    ProjectTitle = Cells(j + 1, 2).Value
    ContractStart = Cells(j + 1, 11).Value
    ContractEnd = Cells(j + 1, 12).Value
    ASPQ = Cells(j + 1, 14).Value

'Paste these information into the output file
Application.Workbooks.Open (OutputPath)

Cells(j + 2, 2).Value = ContractNo
Cells(j + 2, 3).Value = ProjectTitle
Cells(j + 2, 4).Value = ContractStart
Cells(j + 2, 5).Value = ContractEnd
Cells(j + 2, 6).Value = ASPQ

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

'Loop through the bill summaries month by month
'If can find, put the quantity delivered for that month
'If cannot find, set the quantity to zero
Dim MonthTag As Integer
Dim YearTag As Integer
Dim ActiveMonth As String

For m = 1 To MonthRange
    Application.Workbooks.Open (OutputPath)
    MonthTag = Month(Cells(2, 7 + m).Value)
    YearTag = Year(Cells(2, 7 + m).Value)

    Select Case MonthTag
        Case "1"
            ActiveMonth = "JAN" & Right(YearTag, 2)
        Case "2"
            ActiveMonth = "FEB" & Right(YearTag, 2)
        Case "3"
            ActiveMonth = "MAR" & Right(YearTag, 2)
        Case "4"
            ActiveMonth = "APR" & Right(YearTag, 2)
        Case "5"
            ActiveMonth = "MAY" & Right(YearTag, 2)
        Case "6"
            ActiveMonth = "JUN" & Right(YearTag, 2)
        Case "7"
            ActiveMonth = "JUL" & Right(YearTag, 2)
        Case "8"
            ActiveMonth = "AUG" & Right(YearTag, 2)
        Case "9"
            ActiveMonth = "SEP" & Right(YearTag, 2)
        Case "10"
            ActiveMonth = "OCT" & Right(YearTag, 2)
        Case "11"
            ActiveMonth = "NOV" & Right(YearTag, 2)
        Case "12"
            ActiveMonth = "DEC" & Right(YearTag, 2)
    End Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim Qty As Double
    Dim SumQty As Double
    Dim Found As Integer
    Dim SumFound As Integer

    MyFolder = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\bill\"

    If Dir((MyFolder & "\" & YearTag & "\Bill_Summary_Report_" & ActiveMonth & ".xls")) <> "" Then

        Application.Workbooks.Open (MyFolder & "\" & YearTag & "\Bill_Summary_Report_" & ActiveMonth & ".xls")
        Worksheets("Cement").Select

        'Find contract coordinates
        x = 1
        Do Until Cells(x, 1).Value = "Sno"
            x = x + 1
        Loop

        y = 1
        Do Until Cells(x, y).Value = "Contract"
            y = y + 1
        Loop

        'Find Qty coordinates
        p = 1
        Do Until Cells(p, 1).Value = "Product"
            p = p + 1
        Loop

        q = 1
        Do Until Cells(p, q).Value = "C Qty"
            q = q + 1
        Loop

        'Determine the quantity delivered for the month
        'this area is proned with problems since one spacing could distort the data
        'may want to manual check for multiple occurences of contract no!
        n = 1
        SumFound = 0
        SumQty = 0
        Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(17 + n, y).Value)
            If ContractNo = Cells(17 + n, y).Value Then
                Found = 1
                Qty = Cells(19 + n, q).Value
            Else
                Found = 0
                Qty = 0

            End If

        SumFound = SumFound + Found
        SumQty = SumQty + Qty
        n = n + 10
        Loop

        ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Else

        SumQty = 0

    End If

    Application.Workbooks.Open (OutputPath)
    Cells(j + 2, 7 + m).Value = SumQty
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    'MsgBox "m: " & m & vbNewLine & "yr: " & YearTag & vbNewLine & "j: " & j

    Next m

Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Ting Ping : At which line code breaks ? Did you try to debug ?

Comment: Can you add some description of problem?

Comment: Hi, the program was running alright, but halfway through the program (i.e. after running through multiple contracts, it just stopped and exited the subroutine). No error message generated. I couldn't understand why.

Comment: There is no change in the sheet. I'm retrieving contract no. from Final SPQ for eDPSS file and looping through all the bill summaries. Then repeat the process for each and every contract no. There are about 140 contracts, but the program only managed to complete 40+ before stopping.

Comment: "the problem was running alright" lol :)

Comment edited, im writing answer.

Comment: Ting :  Add these to start of your code `On Error GoTo Errhandler` add these lines to bottom of your code `exit sub
Errhandler:
      MsgBox Err.Description, vbInformation` . It will give you the exact error message. Once you get the error message share it with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is somewhere in data.

You have many datetime conversions, maybe one file contains **data with wrong format**, like string instead of date.

Maybe there is a problem with file names (`01` instead of `1` or `1` instead of `01`).

I suggest to temporarily remove file which caused break and see what will happen.

If this will work - try to find problem in that problematic file.

When you find it - try to handle that kind of problem in your code.